# I'm unable to upgrade packages on Ubuntu. Specifically Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

Every time I try to run upgrade, I get the following error.

```
 root@Nixie:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nginx : Depends: nginx-core (< 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3.1~) but 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.4 is installed or
              nginx-full (< 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3.1~) but it is not installed or
              nginx-light (< 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3.1~) but it is not installed or
              nginx-extras (< 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3.1~) but it is not installed or
              nginx-naxsi (< 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3.1~) but it is not installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I run `apt-get -f install`

```
root@Nixie:~# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libxslt1.1 nginx-common nginx-core
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  nginx
The following packages will be upgraded:
  nginx
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/402 kB of archives.
After this operation, 958 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 123867 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../nginx_1.8.1-1~trusty_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking nginx (1.8.1-1~trusty) over (1.4.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.8.1-1~trusty_amd64.deb (--unpack):

 trying to overwrite '/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html', which is also in   package nginx-common 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.4
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/nginx_1.8.1-1~trusty_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should remove the old nginx (1.4.x) and after that install the new one. nginx 1.8.x and 1.4.x have some incompatibility, so you can't upgrade it in easy way.

Comment: Are you saying that they're both currently installed? That won't delete any of my configuration files right?

Comment: No, I'm just saying that you can't "direct" upgrade nginx from 1.4 to 1.8. The same thing with php